# Error handling checking database with else if for existing email

Tags: php, mysql

Im stuck with some code. Im pretty new to this.

If the else statement ($uidcheck) returns false it should execute the elseif statement ($emailcheck). See code below.

```
$username = $_POST['username'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$pwd = $_POST['pwd'];

if (empty($username)) {
    header("Location: ../signup.php?error=empty");
    exit();
}
if (empty($email)) {
    header("Location: ../signup.php?error=empty");
    exit();
}
if (empty($pwd)) {
    header("Location: ../signup.php?error=empty");
    exit();

} else {
        $sql = "SELECT username FROM user WHERE username='$username'";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        $uidcheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);
        if ($uidcheck > 0) {
            header("Location: ../signup.php?error=username");
            exit();

    } elseif ($uidcheck < 0) {

        $sql = "SELECT email FROM user WHERE email='$email'";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        $emailcheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);
        if ($emailcheck > 0) {
            header("Location: ../signup.php?error=email");
            exit();

        } else {

            $sql = "INSERT INTO user (username, email, pwd) 
            VALUES ('$username', '$email', '$pwd')";
            $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

            header("Location: ../index.php");
        }

    }
}
```

When the emailadress already exists in the database it should exit and add a parameter to the header.

Thanks in advance!

Sven

Comment: Whats Going on ? Are you getting any **ERROR** Message or Values not Inserting into DB. What is the issue you are facing.?

Comment: If I type an existing email address I will be linked to the page of this file. namely: http://localhost:8888/newsgo/includes/signup.inc.php (This is the page of the code).

So something goes wrong. What should happen is that there is a parameter behind the URL: http://localhost:8888/newsgo/signup.php?Error=email

Comment: Not sure I understand 100% what you mean but try this

elseif ($uidcheck <= 0)

Answer (score 0):

Your code may does the purpose. But that is not good enough to read/debug.

```
if( !isset($_POST["username"]) || !isset($_POST["email"]) || !isset($_POST["pwd"]) || empty($_POST["username"]) || empty($_POST["email"]) || empty($_POST["pwd"]) )
{
    header("Location: ../signup.php?error=empty");
    exit();
}
$sql = "SELECT username FROM user WHERE username='".mysqli_real_escape_string($username)."'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$uidcheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);
if ($uidcheck > 0) 
{
    header("Location: ../signup.php?error=username");
    exit();
}
else 
{
    $sql = "SELECT email FROM user WHERE email='".mysqli_real_escape_string($email)."'";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    $emailcheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);
    if ($emailcheck > 0) {
        header("Location: ../signup.php?error=email");
        exit();
    }
    else {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO user (username, email, pwd) 
            VALUES ('$username', '$email', '$pwd')";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        header("Location: ../index.php");
    }
}
```

Here are my **Recommendations**:

- Always check if an variable is declared in the scope using `isset()` function. If the value of "username" or "email or "pwd" is ***not submitted*** in the **POST request**, your code will throw a **Fatal Exception** and rendering stops there.....
- **Don't** put the **value submitted** by the User **directly into the SQL query**....This will make your web application **Vulnerable** to [SQL Injection Attack](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp).

Comment: This will do the trick! Only one thing. When the email exists then I still get the username parameter: ?error=username instead of ?error=email.

Comment: @Sven van Djik, that mean the **username** you provided during the request may also be present in the database....

The code will first check If the username exists and then only proceeds to the email checking.......

If thats not the case, feel free to reply.....

Comment: Its not the case. I emptied the DB and made 1 user. The values of that user are empty in the database.

Then when I procide and make a second user with diffrent info I will get an error message that the user already exists.

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

You are checking the MySQL resulted value in a wrong manner. For Example **Email**  is already existed in you DB then your Query results Value, then you don not check with `< or >` just try with either it is empty or not.

```
$username = $_POST['username'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$pwd = $_POST['pwd'];

if (empty($username)) {
    header("Location: ../signup.php?error=empty");
    exit();
}
if (empty($email)) {
    header("Location: ../signup.php?error=empty");
    exit();
}
if (empty($pwd)) {
    header("Location: ../signup.php?error=empty");
    exit();

} else {
    echo "Username check";
        $sql = "SELECT username FROM user WHERE username='$username'";

        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        $uidcheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);
        if (!empty($uidcheck)) {
            header("Location: ../signup.php?error=username");
            exit();
        } elseif (empty($uidcheck)) {
            $sql = "SELECT email FROM user WHERE email='$email'";
            $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
           echo $emailcheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);

        if (!empty($emailcheck)) {
                header("Location: ../signup.php?error=email");
                exit();

        } else {
            echo "asdasd";
            $sql = "INSERT INTO user (username, email, pwd) 
            VALUES ('$username', '$email', '$pwd')";
            $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

            header("Location: ../index.php");
        }

    }
}
```